# Laravel 4: How to use an Accessor in a where-clause

Tags: php, database, laravel-4, eloquent, accessor

Is it possible to use an Accessor for comparison in Laravel 4, for example:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

   // define Accessor
   public function getSpecialNameAttribute()
   {
       return 'Joda';
   }

}

$User = User::where('gender','=','male')->where('specialName','=','Joda');
```

?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can use it to filter query results:

```
User
    ::where('gender','=','male')
    ->get()
    ->filter(function($item) {
        return $item->specialName === 'Luke';
    });
```

(!) Note that filtering will be applied after quering DB, so in case of big data this solution will have performance issues.

For more details I've googled for you [this Collections tutorial](http://daylerees.com/codebright/eloquent-collections).

Also I suggest [query scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes)  may be useful to complete your task in best way.

Comment: Yes, this was the way i'm looking for. In my case, there is no big data, so this is quite enough. Thank you!

Comment: Filter is turning my collection into an object when it is returned as json. Is there a way to tell filter to make it an array?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use it this way.

When you use:

```
$user = User::where('gender','=','male')->where('specialName','=','Joda')->get();
```

you will try to compare `specialName` column in database with `Joda` string.

You cannot use accessor here, because accessor may be very complicated and then Laravel would need to take all data from table in database (for example 100000 records) and calculate accessors for all of them to get for you only records you need (for example 1 record).

You can use accessor only when you have object instance, and you won't be able to use it when querying database.

Comment: Can this be done with a `leftJoin`? May you please show an example of this if possible.